# custom domain redirecting to standard domain

Tags: custom-domain

if anyone can help that would be much appreciated.

we have created a custom domain naming login.xyz.com. This domain is linked to the experience site as well. However, when experience site is opened , the custom domain when reaches the VF page, it changes from my custom domain to xyz.my.site.com.

Enhanced domain is activated in our Org.

Can someone help on this? SF product support is taking so long and it is impacting the customer.